# Collect data from a user -- can't tell who entered the data !

Tags: workflow

```
I can't believe this.
I'm using Collect data from a user to get some data for a form,
via a secondary workflow in moss 2007.
But once the user clicks Complete Task, the System Account marks
the task complete, and thus the 'Modified by' value is always "Sharepoint\System".

So I can't find out who actually gave the data.
So if this isn't the right way, what is?
----------------------------------------------------------------
Here's the version history.
Notice that the assigned-to person is not the user who completed the form,.
---------------------------------------------------------
No. Sort Descending Modified Modified By
3.0 12/27/2010 1:56 PM System Account
Status Completed
% Complete 100 %
---------------------------------------------------------
2.0 12/27/2010 1:56 PM George
Other Comments Thanks and goodbye
Overall Performance 1
On-Time Delivery 2
Cargo Handling 1
Satisfaction 4
Billing Accuracy 4
======================
1.0 12/27/2010 1:52 PM System Account
Title Complete a Vendor Evaluation
Priority (2) Normal
Status Not Started
Assigned To Sharepoint Demo User 3
Start Date 12/27/2010
Workflow Name Vendor Evaluations - Get Data From User
Content Type Complete a Vendor Evaluation
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with workflows in SP2007. Workflows run under the system account so the modified by field will be set to that account. A workaround would be to add an extra field to the list that you use to store the user who is filling out the form in.

Answer (score 0):

You should already know who is filling out the form since you have to assign the task to someone.

Comment: No, you'd only know who was _supposed_ to complete the task. The workflow could not assume that the person who was assigned the task was the one who completed it.